# How to add check constraint for flag column when we don't know exact format in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Here first letter should be an alpha, column may contain any number of data separated by " / " ,for every stating letter I want alphabet, after first letter it may contain 3 or 4 letter. How to do this dynamically.

I am thinking of... first i can find  position of " / " add it to one, here we will get alphabet position then I can check whether it is an alpha or numerical character

Comment: For some reason, this looks like a sequence of codes to me.  If so, you should not be storing them in a string.  You should have a separate row for each code.

Comment: You can do this in T-SQL, but not without a function, and not efficiently. Gordon is right on the money: if it's possible to store these "flags" in a properly normalized way, you should do so. A check for each individual component is much simpler, as it avoids the hairy problem of string splitting in T-SQL.

Comment: You *could* do this with a check constraint, however, you're going to need to create a scalar function to do so, which could ruin performance of your `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements. Ideally, as @GordonLinoff recommended, you need to normalise your data. I would also recommend tagging the version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you just beat me to it.

Comment: And as a bonus: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take on board the comments about normalisation - however you should be able to do this without a UDF.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
Flag VARCHAR(100) CHECK (
                         /*Only contains alpha, digits and slash*/
                         Flag NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9/]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 AND 
                         /*Doesn't end in a slash*/
                         Flag NOT LIKE '%/' AND 
                         /*Start of the string and every slash should be followed by an alpha*/
                        '/' + Flag NOT LIKE '%/[^a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 AND 
                         /*Should never have a digit immediately followed by an alpha*/
                              Flag NOT LIKE '%[0-9][a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 AND 
                         /*Should never have two alpha in a row*/
                              Flag NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 AND            
                         /*Should never have 5 digits in a row*/        
                              Flag NOT LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 AND       
                         /*Should not have codes of less than 4 characters*/    
                             '/' + Flag + '/' NOT LIKE '%/_/%' AND          
                             '/' + Flag + '/' NOT LIKE '%/__/%' AND                 
                             '/' + Flag + '/' NOT LIKE '%/___/%'                                                                                    
                        )
);
```

Comment: I'd upvote this, but technically correct or not, this is the sort of "too clever by half" thing I hope to never see in a database. It's just too hard to maintain if the rules ever change, and too hard to check for edge conditions. (Point in case: the current version deems `'A000/'` to be correct, which is not consistent with deeming `'/A000'` to be incorrect.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - yep would need a lot of tSQLt tests. And of course the OP likely shouldn't be storing it in the first place in this format

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree that this type of solution can be kludgy but is not bad provided that rules don't change too often. I appreciate Martin demonstrating an alternative to using a T-SQL scalar UDF which would be a profoundly worse solution. I would probably have a condition for `NOT LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]%'` which addresses your /A000 example and a number of edge cases.

Comment: @AlanBurstein - though the scalar UDF solution could be a good one soon. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/11/07/introducing-scalar-udf-inlining/

Comment: @MartinSmith - thanks for posting that - great read and great news!